# Change ACL on all objects in bucket with api

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Using google cloud storage Api (json or xml, preferably json)  is there a way to set the ACLs for all objects in a bucket?  I know it is possible to get a list of objects and then iterate and set the ACL for each object individually, but surely there is an easier way.  I know with gsutil your can use setacl -R to setacl on entire bucket.  How about with the API??  I'm working in Java appengine, but can also use the restful api of course.  Any help would be great!

Comment: How about setting the default object ACL on the bucket, so that new objects will automatically get the ACL?

Comment: I want to be able to change existing objects. Setting the default acl is usefull, but it will not do what I need in this case.  I need to change all existing objects.

Comment: Why not just use gsutil then? Is this a one-time operation or do you need to do this often?

Comment: This is an ongoing need.  Basically I have different groups within my app and want a bucket for each group.  I need to update the ACLs as members join/leave the group.  So manually using gsutil is not an option.

Comment: If you want to adjust ACLs as members join/leave the group, please consider using a group grant for your objects. That way you only need to update once (in the group mamagement page), and it affects all objects.

Comment: would this be using google groups?  I need to do this all programmatically btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existing object ACLs are orthogonal to bucket acls. In order to change the acls for all the objects in a bucket you need to do one of the following:

1. List all the objects in the bucket and update each object's acl

   - Take a look at batch requests - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch
2. Use a GroupByEmail or GroupByDomain grant - https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol
3. Add/remove people from your project team - https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/projects

You can change the membership of your group and team without having to go back and update all your objects.

Comment: Here is a full example of using batch requests: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-bulk-delete-python

Comment: thanks for the responses.  Looks like I will have to go with option 1.  Using groupbyemail is not possible in my use case because I need to handle creating, adding/removing members programmatically and there is not a google groups api.